# DidFinish of WKWebview called multiple times while loading the content in webView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, swift5

I am using WKWebView to present web content,But the delegate didFinish is called multiple times Providing the function and delegate methods of WKWebView.Also attached the snap of debug console.

```
     func showWebview() {
        self.webview.addSubview(loadingOverlay.activityIndicator)
        self.loadingOverlay.showOverlay(view: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!))
        let urlString = URL(string: data ?? "")
        let request = URLRequest(url: urlString!)
        self.webview.load(request)
     }
```

```
 extension  PresentWebview: UIWebViewDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: 
 WKNavigation!) {
    ActivityCount += 1
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    ActivityCount -= 1
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [weak self] in
           if self?.ActivityCount == 0 {
            print("This is called")
            self?.loadingOverlay.hideOverlayView()
           }
       }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `self?.loadingOverlay.hideOverlayView()` is causing the issue. Can you please comment this line and check if it stopes getting called multiple times?

Comment: Nopes, I checked this also.@zoha131

Comment: Also try by not adding any subview to the WebView.

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/apple-avadhesh/12200dff778717e3beb5b268cdd338f7

Comment: tried with this also,getting same issue@RTXGamer.

Comment: Yes ,checked this case also @zoha131